# Django Admin. UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, encoding, django-admin

I have views.py and models.py as follows, through the forms I have entered some non-English characters(Other Regional Language), and saved to the database. After submitting if I try to edit with my admin interface. It's giving the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

views.py:

```
def new_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            c = form.save(commit=False)
            c.author = request.user
            c.save()
            return redirect(my_submitted_news)

    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request, 'new_submit.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class News_Post(models.Model):
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Area = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Photo_link = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    News_Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    News = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.News_Title
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.145.155:8080/anuj_borah/news/news_post/11/change/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.6


Template error:
    In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 21
    ascii   11 : {% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}
    12 : 
    13 : {% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-form{% endblock %}
    14 : 
    15 : {% if not is_popup %}
    16 : {% block breadcrumbs %}
    17 : <div class="breadcrumbs">
    18 : <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
    19 : &rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
    20 : &rsaquo; {% if has_change_permission %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %}
    21 : &rsaquo; {% if add %}{% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}{% else %} {{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}  {% endif %}
    22 : </div>
    23 : {% endblock %}
    24 : {% endif %}
    25 : 
    26 : {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
    27 : {% block object-tools %}
    28 : {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
    29 :   <ul class="object-tools">
    30 :     {% block object-tools-items %}
    31 :     <li>


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  315.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  315.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1044.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  739.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py" in _dec
  47.             args[0] = force_text(args[0])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  80.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /anuj_borah/news/news_post/11/change/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Issue with the admin interface . when i try to edit the post with non english character , its giving the same error .

Comment: So what line causes the error? Can you include full stacktrace?

Comment: @Igonato full stacktrace has attached . kindly suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also declare at the top of views.py, forms.py and models.py:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This way you declare the encoding used in the file.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: Pablo Fernandez  i tried , but it did not worked , it giving same problem .

Comment: I would recoomend you define the methond __unicode__ in your class instead of using __str__. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In the `__str__` method convert your title to a unicode object, that should fix the problem:

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self.News_Title, 'utf-8')
```

Also, consider switching to Python 3.

Comment: Igonato  Now i am getting the error  " decoding Unicode is not supported"

Comment: After changing _str__(self):  to __unicode__(self):  my issue resolved . Thanks for your valuable comment and help .

Comment: Any idea what I should do if I'm seeing this while using Py3?

Comment: In my case issue was solved by switching from defining `__str__` to `__unicode__` method.  Thanks @ilak

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django and python 2.7 this fixes it for me:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Utente(models.Model):
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible